# Do I have to pay after upgrading Google Cloud Platform upgrade

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have registered Google Cloud Platform last year and today I just upgraded my GCP account.
I wonder if I will be charged after the upgrade?

Kind regards,

Haruka

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions/255746#255746)

Answer (score 1):

Once your free tier ends you need to upgrade , and any usage above Free Tier usage limits is automatically billed at standard rates.

Their docs clearly mention `You should be aware that if you do not upgrade to a paid account after the free trial ends, your Google Compute Engine resources might be removed. Removed resources are not recoverable.`

https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier

You can calculate an estimate here
https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator?skip_cache=true